# Blazor Server / Assembly Hot Reload without Visual Studio Popup

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

I'm  building a web app where I develop sort of simultaneously in a Blazor Server project and a Blazor Web Assembly project.  I want hot-reload to be enabled, so changes are applied on save.

The desired behavior is for this to happen automatically, in the background.  If for some reason Browser Reload cannot be applied, a little status bar notification would be fine.

What is happening instead is that every I save a file that cannot be reloaded, I get an annoying modal popup that prevents me from doing anything until I close it.  The option is to disable hot-reload, but that is not what I want either.  I just don't need to stop everything if it fails.

Sometimes I make multiple changes that I know will require a reload, and I'm waiting to do a rebuild until I've completed all of them, but in practice what happens is that I get a modal popup every time I save a file even if I don't need it to be reloaded.

This is very frustrating.  Is there another way to get hot-reload working without this annoying behavior?

Visual Studio Community 2022